# Issue opening Paypal Payment URL in Android Webview or browser

Tags: android, paypal, webview, payment

In my app I am sending price and subscription ID details to the server and server is returning me with payment url which at the moment looking like this:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=abcabcabc@samplewebsite.com&item_name=Upload%20Fund&amount=105&notify_url=http://samplewebsite.com/api/sample/SubscriptionActive?ftk=0&tax=5&return=http://samplewebsite.com/api/sample/SubscriptionActive?ftk=0&tax=5

this url works just fine on pc browser or in mobile browser if copy pasted in as a link. but when I try to open it in Webview link successfully gets to the webview as it is but webview doesnt open it nor the browser(opening with Intent).

How to solve this problem in webview or do i need paypal sdk? But I am not having any KEY for Paypal.

Thanks

Comment: same problem(((

Comment: did you solve it?